# Mails and messages are not being sent after successful order placement

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, email, messages, minified-js

Few days before I had minified all the `JS` files in my Magento store and after that, both the mails and the messages that we had configured to fire on successful order placement is not working.

Is this happening because of the minification of any particular JS file?

Is any `JS` file is linked to email and message sending?

Kindly let me know.

Comment: have yoou checked confuguration ?  admin / system / configuration / SALES / Sales Emails / Order /

Comment: Have you checked the cron is running fine or not? Also check the log files if there is any error regarding emails.

Answer (score 0):

Its not related to JS, you should check Mail sending settings in backend admin>> system>>configuration >> System >> Mail sending Settings